Cannot start weaviate server. Getting "transformer remote inference service not ready"
My yaml is as follows
version: '3.4'
services:
  weaviate:
    image: cr.weaviate.io/semitechnologies/weaviate:1.25.0
    restart: on-failure:0
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    - 50051:50051
    volumes:
    - /home/nitin/repo/central/Gen_AI/weaviate/volume:/var/lib/weaviate
    environment:
      QUERY_DEFAULTS_LIMIT: 20
      AUTHENTICATION_ANONYMOUS_ACCESS_ENABLED: 'true'
      PERSISTENCE_DATA_PATH: "/var/lib/weaviate"
      DEFAULT_VECTORIZER_MODULE: 'none'
      ENABLE_MODULES: text2vec-transformers
      TRANSFORMERS_INFERENCE_API: http://t2v-transformers:8080
      CLUSTER_HOSTNAME: 'tenant_1'

when I try to spin up a local weaviate server with
sudo docker compose -f ./docker-compose.yaml up
I get
{"action":"transformer_remote_wait_for_startup","error":"send check ready request: Get \"http://t2v-transformers:8080/.well-known/ready\": dial tcp: lookup t2v-transformers on 127.0.0.11:53: server misbehaving","level":"warning","msg":"transformer remote inference service not ready","time":"2024-05-20T07:09:47Z"}

I do not know my way around the yaml much. Please help me get the weaviate service running locally

That's because of ENABLE_MODULES: text2vec-transformers
If you enable the transformers module (docs) Weaviate expects that it can reach that service (in this specific example here: TRANSFORMERS_INFERENCE_API: http://t2v-transformers:8080). In your Dockerfile, t2v-transformers isn't created, hence Weaviate can't find it.
To solve your issue, you can do two things.
Run Weaviate without the transformers module
You want this if you bring your own vector embeddings.
You simply run it without any modules, as can be found in the docs here.
---
version: '3.4'
services:
  weaviate:
    command:
    - --host
    - 0.0.0.0
    - --port
    - '8080'
    - --scheme
    - http
    image: cr.weaviate.io/semitechnologies/weaviate:1.25.1
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    - 50051:50051
    volumes:
    - weaviate_data:/var/lib/weaviate
    restart: on-failure:0
    environment:
      QUERY_DEFAULTS_LIMIT: 25
      AUTHENTICATION_ANONYMOUS_ACCESS_ENABLED: 'true'
      PERSISTENCE_DATA_PATH: '/var/lib/weaviate'
      DEFAULT_VECTORIZER_MODULE: 'none'
      ENABLE_MODULES: ''
      CLUSTER_HOSTNAME: 'node1'
volumes:
  weaviate_data:
...

Run Weaviate with the transformers module
You should use this one if you want to locally vectorize your data using the transformers container, as can be found in the docs here.
version: '3.4'
services:
  weaviate:
    image: cr.weaviate.io/semitechnologies/weaviate:1.25.1
    restart: on-failure:0
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    - 50051:50051
    environment:
      QUERY_DEFAULTS_LIMIT: 20
      AUTHENTICATION_ANONYMOUS_ACCESS_ENABLED: 'true'
      PERSISTENCE_DATA_PATH: "./data"
      DEFAULT_VECTORIZER_MODULE: text2vec-transformers
      ENABLE_MODULES: text2vec-transformers
      TRANSFORMERS_INFERENCE_API: http://t2v-transformers:8080
      CLUSTER_HOSTNAME: 'node1'
  t2v-transformers:
    image: cr.weaviate.io/semitechnologies/transformers-inference:sentence-transformers-multi-qa-MiniLM-L6-cos-v1
    environment:
      ENABLE_CUDA: 0 # set to 1 to enable
      # NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: all # enable if running with CUDA

